# In C++, How can we use functions from pre-declared classes

Tags: c++, class

Why doesn't `getString()` function work. How should I do it?

```
class A;
class B;
{
    A* a;
    char* someFunction() {return a->getString();}
}
class A
{
    char* getString() {..} // This works fine
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the *definition* of class before you can actually use its member function. The compiler needs to know what belongs to the class.

The way to do this would be

1. Provide proper access to methods ( or use `friend` )
2. Define the methods outside the class declaration.

---

```
class A;
    class B
    {
        public:

        A* a;
       char * someFunction() ;
    };

class A
{
    public:
    char* getString() { } 
};

char* B::  someFunction() {return a->getString();}
```